# Replace emoji names to its code

Tags: jquery, replace, emoji

I use [emojiarea](https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea) to make a textarea with Emoji support. When I type a message with Emoji and send it, it uses an emoji name like :smile: but I want to replace this name with its code as in [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji). So the problem is to find a file or something, where I can find the required replacement.
Please, any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [gemoji project](https://github.com/github/gemoji) which has a json database for the emojis [here](https://github.com/github/gemoji/blob/master/db/emoji.json).

For each entry in the database, the "alias" field will have to be replaced by the "emoji" field.

```
[
  {
    "emoji": ""
  , "description": "smiling face with open mouth and smiling eyes"
  , "aliases": [
      "smile"
    ]
  , "tags": [
      "happy"
    , "joy"
    , "pleased"
    ]
  }
, {
    "emoji": ""
  , "description": "smiling face with open mouth"
  , "aliases": [
      "smiley"
    ]
  , "tags": [
      "happy"
    , "joy"
    , "haha"
    ]
  }

  // Etc.
]
```